# What do you get for resetting a character's level?

Tags: fire-emblem-warriors

In the most recent update to Fire Emblem Warriors (3/28/18), there was an option added to the temple at the camp:  **Level Reset**.  The description says "Get materials when resetting a character to level 1."  There are certainly materials that I need and characters that I don't use as much as others, so I'm considering taking this action.

[image: Level Reset: Get materials when resetting a character to level 1]

But what exactly do you get for doing this?  It costs **1,000,000 gold**, and raising that character back up wouldn't be a walk in the park so it's not an action I would take lightly.  I don't need a bunch of gold materials or random materials that I might already have a lot of.  I want to make sure that if I reset my character's level, it's going to be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While resetting your character to lv1 costs a lot of gold, you can actually see the materials you will obtain. By clicking on the character you wish reset, this opens a confirmation window listing the materials you will obtain after the level reset. Below is a sample from [Update 1.5 overview](http://youtu.be/pTQZpAutiZY) video on YouTube

[image]

The level of the character prior to resetting is related to how many materials you obtain. For a LV96 Rowan in the video, you’d receive 9 Rowan’s Capes and 19 Rowan’s Bucklers. However, for a lv36 Rowan, I would have only received 3 Rowan’s Capes and 7 Rowan’s Bucklers

Based on the numbers of items received, this calculates to 10% of the characters level for the first item listed and the 20% of the characters level for the second item listed, both rounding down to the nearest whole number.